# Select mutiple cell using Cells() function

Tags: excel, cells, vba

```
          A    B    C  
1        100  101  102
2        103  104  105
3        106  107  108
```

How can I select only `C1` and `A3` cell together?

```
Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 1)).Select
```

That selects it as a range instead of just those specific cells.

*I know I haven't provided my code, but just looking for a quick advice.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub RangeRover()
Range("A3,C1").Select
End Sub
```

and if you really want to use *Cells()* then:

```
Sub ytrewq()
Union(Cells(1, 3), Cells(3, 1)).Select
End Sub
```